# How to view crash log?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testing

I maked test app and send it to my friend with Ad-hoc. He crashed my app. Can you help me, how can I to view why or read crash-log?

Comment: You should look at this:http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this website, this is free. Just create an account add the testflight key in your app give by them, then upload it in this website, this will generate a link, send it your friend. If any crash occurs it will recorded, you can symbolize the crash log by uploading .dsym file

http://testflightapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try crashlytics. http://try.crashlytics.com
It will symbolicate crash reports and tally up them.

Comment: Try to post open sources resources!!

Comment: Your answer is also non open source, right?

Comment: Nope... Check out its open source, any one can use it.

Comment: Where can I find the source code of this SDK? https://www.testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/download/